# Trying to write a 2D array to a .csv and not all the cells are copied over

Tags: c#, csv

I have a several arrays/matrices that I am trying to copy to a .csv using C# but I'm having issues.  The one I will show you is for a [12,480] matrix.  I run the code and all of the first 11 rows copy fully, but the last 20 values in the 12th row do not get copied into the .csv.  I've displayed the 'myArray' in the console and all the values are there with a total matrix length of 5760.  If you have any idea what is happening, please let me know. I have other arrays that fill out 474 out of 480 values, 427 out of 480 values, and 5712 out of 5760 values.

NOTE:  The code is working, just the last 20 values in the array won't copy to .csv.  I've also attached an image of the .csv to give you a better idea of what is happening.  [The end of the matrix with the missing values highlighted in yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwRyv.png)

```
private static void CreateuCSV(double[,] myArray) 
{
    StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("location")
    for (int i = 0; i <12; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 480; j++)
        {
            file.Write(myArray[i,j];
            file.Write(",");
        }
        file.Write("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds to me like there may be some value in the matrices, which terminates the writing to the .csv file? Possibly check the column at the first instance of the matrice that isn't written to the .csv and compare to the other matrices, and see what kind of format and value is there. Also, if you wrap your for loops in a try catch block, you could catch an Exception and see what it's message is.

Comment: Besides of your problem: even if you do know the size of a array, do not hard-code its dimensions. Instead use `myArray.GetLength(0)` and `myArray.GetLength(1)`

Comment: Joe - That is what I initially had, but it was giving me the same problem.  I changed to the hard-coded dimensions to see if it happened to change anything.

Comment: @SamuelOgletree Did you do either of my suggestions?

Comment: Flagged this as unresponsive

Comment: Ryan Wilson - I'm brand new to C#, so I wasn't aware of the terminology  so i've been reading up on it and will get back to you shortly.

Answer (score 0):

This generates a square array of the desired size in the csv...

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int rows = 12, cols = 480;
            double[,] nums = new double[rows, cols];
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                {
                    nums[i, j] = j;
                }
            }

            CreateCSV(nums);
        }

        private static void CreateCSV(double[,] myArray)
        {
            var rows = myArray.GetLength(0);
            var cols = myArray.GetLength(1);

            using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("2dArrayOut.csv"))
            {
                file.AutoFlush = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                    {
                        file.Write($"{myArray[i, j]},");
                    }
                    file.Write("\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is damn near exactly what my code looks like, minus the row and column variables.  I altered mine to include those and its still giving me the same problem.

Comment: What about closing/disposing the Stream with the using(){...} statement?  You can also make sure you're flushing the stream with file.AutoFlush = true;

Comment: Unless the array is jagged and/or not actually the size you claim it to be (you didn't include the array init code), then this answer should be accepted.

Comment: One other thought - You said you had several different arrays that you are trying to output to csv: are you somehow interleaving the output calls with different sized arrays?  From your original code we can already see that you weren't closing/disposing the output streams properly.  Using{}/Close()/Dispose() are interchangeable in the managed stream implementations.  Microsoft says - "You must call Close to ensure that all data is correctly written out to the underlying stream..."  So, I think that just scoping the StreamWriter in the using block (calling Dispose()) should fix the issue.